# What do the different types of ITaskbarList do?

Tags: windows, taskbar

So far I've used `ITaskbarList` and `ITaskbarList3` to use the taskbar icon's progress bar; however, I'm curious as to what `ITaskbarList2` and `ITaskbarList4` are used for?

Comment: Have you considered looking them up in MSDN? [`ITaskBarList2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774638(v=vs.85).aspx), [`ITaskBarList4`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562040(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Huh, could've sworn that didn't show up in a search, maybe I was looking at the wrong thing, thanks! Also, you could've just posted that as an answer.

Comment: Go ahead and write up your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Raymond, I checked out the MSDN and found that:

- `ITaskbarList2` extends `ITaskbarList` and adds a method to mark a window as fullscreen
- `ITaskbarList4` extends `ITaskbarList3` and adds a method to change the tab properties

So, each ITaskbar# builds upon the previous one.